# Cron job for listening the queue every minutes crashes the mysql database server

Tags: laravel-5, cron, mediatemple

Cron job for scheduler which runs queue listen command in background creates the excessive load in mediatemple Dv hosting server and crash mysql connnection.
The processes and their children generating load look like this:

_ /usr/bin/php artisan emails:dealinit
    _ /usr/bin/php artisan queue:work  --queue=default --delay=0 --memory=128 --sleep=3 --tries=0 --env=local

- - - - - php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1 is the command which i have used as per official documentation.

Comment: This runs a scripts every minute, and if you are using MySQL as the Queue driver, that will create load, however, your server should be able to handle such load, except if your jobs, and they keep written to your DB.

Comment: I have removed the queue:listen command from the scheduler and simply run the logger which writes log file every 1 minute but same problem mysql server connection get lost and server load reaches excessive above 95%. But this was not problem in hostgator.